# How does sed interpret the following statement

Tags: shell, unix, sed, ksh, gnu

Salute to all devs,

Excuse me for addressing this question, but I am a little noob, when it comes to shell scripting, I am still learning (please bear with me).

Ok, long story short... I have met this shell command in someone script:

```
sed -e 1,\$s/a/${b}  myfile > myfile_1
```

What does 1 stands for? and does "\" escape the character "$"?

Thank you devs.

Comment: Thanks for tip Cyrus :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where the line is executed.

Assuming it is executed in `bash` or `ksh` or something similar, the line means to execute `sed` with the script `1,$s/a/` with the contents of the shell variable `b` appended.  Apparently, it is expected that the value of `b` should terminate the `s` instruction, otherwise `sed` will complain.

It's impossible to tell what the script will do without knowing the value of `b` -- it may simply complete the `s` instruction, for substituting something for `a` on every line, but it could contain any number of additional instructions.

Comment: Additionally, `1,$` is not required in my opinion, as it says "do this for every line", which is the default behaviour anyway.

Comment: @shinobi Thank you for the explanation, now it's more clear.

Comment: @Benjamin W. Thank you, I have just rewritten the command removing the unnecessary instruction "1,$".